# Signal sigabrt when adding a view

Tags: ios, xcode, sigabrt

Just when starting on different projects on Xcode (Single view, Master-detail,...)
I meet always the thread 1 : Signal sigabrt warning which stops my iOS simulator.

For this simulation, I start from a single view project with one button linked to another single view. Nothing complicated, even if I'm new in iOS dev world.

Thanks for helping me

```
Thread backtrace :
2013-06-25 18:54:39.356 App4[1313:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception          'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is       managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c90012 0x10cde7e 0x467f31 0x459b99 0x459c14 0x10e1705 0x152c0 0x15258 0xd6021 0xd657f     0xd56e8 0x44cef 0x44f02 0x22d4a 0x14698 0x1bebdf9 0x1bebad0 0x1c05bf5 0x1c05962 0x1c36bb6     0x1c35f44 0x1c35e1b 0x1bea7e3 0x1bea668 0x11ffc 0x1fad 0x1ed5 0x1)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CalViewController : UIViewController

@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CalAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end


#import "CalViewController.h"

@interface CalViewController ()

@end

@implementation CalViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
 [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with the connection, it is that you are trying to push a new view controller to your navigation controller, but your app does not use a navigation controller. You can fix this in a couple ways. First, if you want a navigation controller, put your root view inside of the navigation controller and then the push segue will work, or you can just change the type of the segue to something like modal or replace.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your button's method is called.If you are using storyboard then check your button's and view's connection.Also check your segue is set properly between two views.If problem still persist try to debug your code line by line. Hope this might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using storyboard all you need to do is select your main view in and select “Editor” in the xcode menu bar on top of screen and select “Embed in”, followed by “Navigation Controller”.

Here is a more in depth guide..

http://www.appcoda.com/use-storyboards-to-build-navigation-controller-and-table-view/